# Own implementation of SkipPolicy interface in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to give own implementation of RetryPolicy interface. Below is my code. I am able to give implementation of canRetry method but not sure about open, close & registerThrowable method. How to give their implementation.

When ever I am running my code the retry happens for infinite number of times. flow goes to open method where return type is null. Which is where i think is causing. So my RetryPlolicy is not working as expected.

```
@Slf4j
public class RecordRetryPolicy implements RetryPolicy {

  public static final int MAX_RETRY_COUNT = 3;


  @Override
  public boolean canRetry(RetryContext retryContext) {
    Throwable t = retryContext.getLastThrowable();
    if ((t instanceof BillingException||t instanceof InternalServerException) && retryContext.getRetryCount() <= MAX_RETRY_COUNT) {
      log.warn("1st block in canRetry");
      return true;
    } else  if (t instanceof InternalServerException && retryContext.getRetryCount() <= MAX_RETRY_COUNT){
      log.warn("2nd block in canRetry");
      return true;
    } else {
      log.warn("3rd block in canRetry");
      return false;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public RetryContext open(RetryContext retryContext) {
    //return retryContext.getParent();
           return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void close(RetryContext retryContext) {

  }

  @Override
  public void registerThrowable(RetryContext retryContext, Throwable throwable) {

  }
}
```

My Step is defines as

```
 @Bean
  public Step InfoStep(JpaTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    ExponentialBackOffPolicy exponentialBackOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
    exponentialBackOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(1000);
    exponentialBackOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(16000);
    exponentialBackOffPolicy.setMultiplier(4.0);

    return new StepBuilder("read-step", jobRepository)
        .<ShopInfo, ShopInfo>chunk(10, transactionManager)
        .reader(dataInfoReader())
        .processor(dataInfoProcessor())
        .writer(dataInfoWriter())
        .taskExecutor(dataTaskExecutor())
        .faultTolerant()
        .retryPolicy(retryPolicy())
        .backOffPolicy(exponentialBackOffPolicy)
        .skipPolicy(skipPolicy())
        .build();
  }

@Bean
  public RecordSkipPolicy skipPolicy(){
    return new RecordSkipPolicy();
  }

  @Bean
  public RecordRetryPolicy retryPolicy(){
    return new RecordRetryPolicy();
  }
```

What implementation should be give for open, close & registerThrowable method.

Answer (score 1):

> not sure about open, close & registerThrowable method. How to give their implementation.

`open`/`close` are for acquiring/releasing any resources needed by the policy . `registerThrowable` is used to register an exception in the retry context so it can be used to decide what to do in the subsequent retry attempt.

Spring Retry provides several implementations of `RetryPolicy` (see this [package](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/tree/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/retry/policy)) from which you can get inspiration.